# Global Variable in PHP for Login and SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cookies, global-variables

After logging in from a PHP Form a cookie is set which contains the `admin_id` value.

My PHP application retrieves it from cookies and stores the value of cookie in variable lets say `$admin_id=$_COOKIE[admin_id]`.

I will be using it in PHP SQL Query such as `select * from $table where admin_id='$admin_id' and  id = '$id'`

I have a common `head.php` file being called before all the files.

Once the value is stored in variable `$admin_id` it should be globally accessible throughout the entire application of PHP of various queries in different functions and files. How can I do it so?

Comment: so, what's the question/problem?

Comment: i have changed the question ....hope it helps

Comment: Cookies should work, and/or sessions while making sure to check if they're set/not empty.

Comment: So if a non-admin logs in and modifies their browser cookie's `admin_id` value then they can become admin? Better yet, an admin logs in and wants to get a different admin fired so they change their cookie and perform malicious tasks.

Comment: they are set and i can retrieve it...i want it to be globally accessible from all files

Comment: so use an included file for all files.

Comment: it will be verifying it from databses everytie. could you please explain included

Comment: `include('global_settings.php');` in all files and control it from there. You'd have "one" file to control here. or `require` - `include_once` - `require_once`.

Comment: store the admin_id in session and use your head.php to retrieve the session variable. storing in cookies is not advisable as they can destroy by the user

Comment: Till that its okay but when i use it in variables the variable value is blank

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your logic:

cookies can be set from browser, so an user setting admin_id=1 can access to your website as admin.

You probably want to save it in session, so `$_SESSION['admin_id'] = $adminId;`

Then you can use `$_SESSION['admin_id']` where you want.

You need to set `session_start()` before any output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it as `global`, and then, if you're calling it from another function, use `global` again

```
global $myVariable = "myValue";

function myCoolFunction() {
    global $myVariable;
    echo $myVariable; // will echo "myValue"
}
```

By the way, you could also use:

```
"select * from $table where admin_id='{$_COOKIE["admin_id"]}' and  id = '$id'"
```

The quotes inside the brackets won't break the first ones